# GPG - exported secret key with public too

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, gnupg

I tried to export public key from my keyring. Then I imported my public key in another keyring. I find the private key too in the 2nd keyring and I can sign files from the 2nd keyring. Why is this possible?

```
-K = list private keys  /  -k = list public keys

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./K -K
./K
---
sec   rsa4096/5CF17A855E7A80B6 2020-02-15 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = 9B0D 8B76 9F11 E766 0C64  C295 5CF1 7A85 5E7A 80B6
uid                 [ultimate] Ama Ama Me (No Comment) <a@m.c>
ssb   rsa4096/89B1B6657E669E13 2020-02-15 [E]
ssb   rsa4096/2FDAA73DFB9A6711 2020-02-15 [S]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./K -k
./K
---
pub   rsa4096/5CF17A855E7A80B6 2020-02-15 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = 9B0D 8B76 9F11 E766 0C64  C295 5CF1 7A85 5E7A 80B6
uid                 [ultimate] Ama Ama Me (No Comment) <a@m.c>
sub   rsa4096/89B1B6657E669E13 2020-02-15 [E]
sub   rsa4096/2FDAA73DFB9A6711 2020-02-15 [S]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./K -o KPUB --export 5CF17A855E7A80B6
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./K4 --import KPUB

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./K4 -K
./K4
----
sec   rsa4096/5CF17A855E7A80B6 2020-02-15 [SC]
      Key fingerprint = 9B0D 8B76 9F11 E766 0C64  C295 5CF1 7A85 5E7A 80B6
uid                 [ultimate] Ama Ama Me (No Comment) <a@m.c>
ssb   rsa4096/89B1B6657E669E13 2020-02-15 [E]
ssb   rsa4096/2FDAA73DFB9A6711 2020-02-15 [S]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./K4 -o file.firmato -sau 5CF17A855E7A80B6! file
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./K4 -o file.firmato -sau 2FDAA73DFB9A6711! file
```

The KPUB file seems to be an only public key file:

```
gpg --list-packets KPUB 
# off=0 ctb=99 tag=6 hlen=3 plen=525
:public key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1581792429, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 5CF17A855E7A80B6
# off=528 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=31
:user ID packet: "Ama Ama Me (No Comment) <a@m.c>"
# off=561 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=590
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 5CF17A855E7A80B6
    version 4, created 1581792429, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
    digest algo 10, begin of digest 13 b1
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 9B0D8B769F11E7660C64C2955CF17A855E7A80B6)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2020-02-15)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 03)
    hashed subpkt 11 len 4 (pref-sym-algos: 9 8 7 2)
    hashed subpkt 21 len 5 (pref-hash-algos: 10 9 8 11 2)
    hashed subpkt 22 len 3 (pref-zip-algos: 2 3 1)
    hashed subpkt 30 len 1 (features: 01)
    hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (keyserver preferences: 80)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 5CF17A855E7A80B6)
    data: [4095 bits]
# off=1154 ctb=b9 tag=14 hlen=3 plen=525
:public sub key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1581792429, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 89B1B6657E669E13
# off=1682 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=566
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 5CF17A855E7A80B6
    version 4, created 1581792429, md5len 0, sigclass 0x18
    digest algo 10, begin of digest 61 ad
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 9B0D8B769F11E7660C64C2955CF17A855E7A80B6)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2020-02-15)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 0C)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 5CF17A855E7A80B6)
    data: [4096 bits]
# off=2251 ctb=b9 tag=14 hlen=3 plen=525
:public sub key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1581793239, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 2FDAA73DFB9A6711
# off=2779 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=1132
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 5CF17A855E7A80B6
    version 4, created 1581793239, md5len 0, sigclass 0x18
    digest algo 10, begin of digest 69 2f
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 9B0D8B769F11E7660C64C2955CF17A855E7A80B6)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2020-02-15)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 02)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 5CF17A855E7A80B6)
    subpkt 32 len 563 (signature: v4, class 0x19, algo 1, digest algo 10)
    data: [4096 bits]
```

Comment: You should ask this question on the gnupg mailing list: https://lists.gnupg.org/mailman/listinfo/gnupg-users